# How to use ids from MongoDB for keys of React list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, interface, key

I am creating a list of items using React, Express and MongoDB.

Items of an array of the list are retrieved from MongoDB, displayed in a component and the user can add new items (and save them in MongoDB).

The problem is that `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"` is shown because new elements are added to the list with a `key` attribute that equals to `undefined` (I'm trying to achieve is to use ids generated by MongoDB as `key`).

App.tsx (**HERE the list of items is fetched with ids generated by MongoDB**)

```
export default function App() {
    const [ExpenseAndAmountList, setExpenseAndAmountList] = useState<
      Array<{
        id: string,
        expenseTitle: string,
        expenseAmount: string,
      }>
    >([]);


 useEffect(() => {
    const expensesListResp = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
      .then(
        response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []));
    }
    expensesListResp();
  }, []);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ExpenseAmountInputContainer 
          expenseAndAmountList={ExpenseAndAmountList}
          setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
          setTotalExpensesAmount={setTotalExpensesAmount}
          totalExpenses={TotalExpensesAmount}
        />

        <DynamicList 
          expenseAndAmountList={ExpenseAndAmountList} 
          currencySymbol={Currency}
          setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

DynamicList.tsx (**HERE I can log out the list from MongoDB and are trying to assign `key={item.id}` but when the whole app is rendered the value `key` of each list item = `undefined`**)

```
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
  interface ListItemsArray {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    currencySymbol: string;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

  const DynamicList: React.FC<ListItemsArray> = (
    {
      expenseAndAmountList, 
      currencySymbol,
      setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: ListItemsArray) => {

    return (
        <>
            <List>
                {expenseAndAmountList.map(item => (
                  <ExpensesListItem
                    key={item.id}
                    expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle} 
                    expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}
                    currencySymbol={currencySymbol}
                    item={item}
                    items={expenseAndAmountList}
                    setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
                  />
                ))} 
            </List>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default DynamicList;
```

ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx (**HERE items are posted to MongoDB list without any ids**)

```
interface Props {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void; 
}

const ExpenseAmountInputContainer: React.FC<Props> = (
        {
            expenseAndAmountList, 
            setExpenseAndAmountList,
        }: Props
    ) => {
    
    const [Expense, setExpense] = useState<string>('');
    const [Amount, setAmount] = useState<string>('');

    const AddItemToList = () => {
        if (Expense !== '' && Amount !== '' && Number(Amount) > 0) {

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', 
            {
                expenseTitle: Expense,
                expenseAmount: Amount
            });
            
            setExpense("");
            setAmount("");

            const expensesListResp = async () => {
                await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
                .then(
                response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []));
            }
            expensesListResp();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <InputItem 
                onChange={setExpense} 
                onBlur={setExpense} 
                title="Expense" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Item title" 
                value={Expense}
            />
            <InputItem 
                onChange={setAmount}  
                onBlur={setAmount}  
                title="Amount" 
                type="number" 
                placeholder="Expense cost" 
                value={Amount}
            />
            <AddButton 
                onClick={AddItemToList} 
                content="Add expense"

            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExpenseAmountInputContainer;
```

ExpensesListItem.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';

interface Props {
    expenseTitle: string;
    id: string;
    expenseAmount: string;
    currencySymbol: string;
    item: ExpenseAndAmountObject;
    items: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

const ExpensesListItem: React.FC<Props> = (
    {
        expenseTitle,
        id
    }: Props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <ListItem className="list-item">
                <ListItemText primary={expenseTitle} secondary={id}/>
            </ListItem>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default ExpensesListItem;
```

ExpenseAndAmountObject.tsx (interface used at ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx)

```
export interface ExpenseAndAmountObject {
    id: string,
    expenseTitle: string,
    expenseAmount: string,
}
```

**Please note -** I assume, `key={item.id}`in DynamicList.tsx equals to `undefined` because an object in the list that is fetched from the DB has an key `_id` (WITH UNDERSLASH) (e.g. `{_id: "60c97ae5ae534110361f359e", expenseTitle: "b", expenseAmount: "2", __v: 0}`) meanwhile the interface `ExpenseAndAmountObject` that I use to iterate through the list has a key `id`).

Also, data is successfully fetched since `expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle}` and  `expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}` have values.

How could I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Only render components after the data is fetched and put in the state by using `ExpenseAndAmountList && <DynamicList {...props}/>`

Comment: The problem is not that data is not fetched since `expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle}` and  `expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}` have values

Comment: Did you console logged the list and see what's its structure and if the `id` is defined there?

Comment: yes, I'm using a Chrome plugin to check the values of props. so, expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle} and expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount} have correct values and key={item.id} of the list items have values of `undefined`

Comment: maybe that's because an object in the list that is fetched from the DB has an key `_id` (WITH UNDERSLASH) (e.g. `{_id: "60c97ae5ae534110361f359e", expenseTitle: "b", expenseAmount: "2", __v: 0}`) meanwhile the interface `ExpenseAndAmountObject` that I use to iterate through the list has a key `id`).

Comment: Don't check item, check `ExpenseAndAmountList`

Comment: I've also consoled out `expenseAndAmountList` inside `<DynamicList>` and the whole list of object is consoled out

Comment: and the id is also undefined when other properties are defined? what is the id key in the console? `id` or `_id`? Have you tried using `item._id` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: When `expenseAndAmountList` is consoled out inside `<DynamicList>` the items of the list in the array have a format of ` {_id: "60cada13ae534110361f368b", expenseTitle: "er", expenseAmount: "4", __v: 0}` ( the first  property is `_id`, none of the values are undefined)

However, the value of prop `id` inside `<ExpensesListItem>` = `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that while sending a response from the backend the getters are true

```js
res.json({places:places.map((place) => place.toObject({getters:true}))})
```

Because my error was solved by making these changes